# Missing mandatory Classpath entries. Resolve Project Problems. in Apache NetBeans

Tags: java, netbeans

I'm working on a Java web application in Apache NetBeans. Everything is working well, but a warning message appears at the package level (first line):

> Missing mandatory Classpath entries. Resolve Project Problems.

Here is a screenshot of that problem in the IDE:

[image: Missing mandatory Classpath entries. Resolve Project Problems.]

The yellow bulb offers me the possibility to solve the problem, but it doesn't work.

Comment: _"...it doesn't work"_?  You need to be more specific than that.

Answer (score 1):

Did you see any kind of alert? Like this, or maybe at the bottom, when you first load the project [Error Missing Mandatory ClassPath](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vNywu.png)? If this is your case, try clicking on the message.Netbeans need to donwload some extra files.  I had the same problem and it worked for me

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33155414)

Answer (score -1):

click resolve,problems window shows nothing